# Move bunch source file code in specific section of linker script

Tags: c, linker, stm32, compiler-optimization, ld

I have learned that using `__attribute__ ((section(".section_name")))`, I can move function or variable at specific section as per defined in linker script. But I have a bunch of C source files for which I wish to move all of that code in a specific section with a simple method **instead of writing the above command for each of the function/variable declarations**.

The same way I have some mode C files for which I need to move them into other defined sections.

Writing `__attribute__ ((section(".section_name")))` For every function and Variable will be time consuming and complex process. Can anyone have an alternate method to apply a specific section for the whole file instead of every function?

Answer (score 4):

Are you exaggerating when you say *"writing `__attribute__ ((section(".section_name")))` for every function and Variable will be time consuming and complex process"*?

*Ctx*'s proposal is a viable solution. But when you revisit your code in half a year's time, you will have a hard time remembering why and how it works. And it will add a lot of extra effort when you move to a different build system.

A more pragmatic solution would be to use a macro:

```
#define MY_SECTION __attribute__ ((section(".section_name")))
```

Using the macro creates easy to read and understandable code with no hidden linker magic:

```
int variable MY_SECTION = 10;

int sqr(int n1) MY_SECTION;
```

Comment: Well, of course this is a good way. But, well... It is exactly what the OP explicitly doesn't want to, be it a macro or not. "Can anyone have an alternate method to apply a specific section for the whole file instead of every function?" is simply not answered here.

Comment: @Ctx I often take the liberty to propose solutions that I think are in the OP's best interest even though he/she might have asked from something slightly different. The good thing about StackOverflow is that a question can have multiple reasonable answers and that the OP and later visitors can implement the one that fits best for their particular context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys... @Codo I am using different SDKs in my project with FreeRTOS MPU support. So, I need to place all third party codes in different section for security. So, As i mentioned earlier I cannot go with __attribute__ ((section(".section_name"))) approach as SDK files are huge in number.

Comment: @Codo I understand this in general, but in this case that solution was _explicitly ruled out_ in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linker script for this. First, fetch the default linker script:

> $ ld --verbose

There is a `SECTIONS` section included, which you have to modify:

```
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
...
```

Now, at the location where you want your new section to appear, place the following command:

```
.mysection : { obj1.o obj2.o }
```

This places all symbols of the specified object files into the specified section. You can also restrict this to specific input sections, for example

```
.mysection : { obj1.o(.text) obj2.o(.data) }
```

You can also use wildcards for the file name specification:

```
.mysection : { sdk/files_*.o }
```

For further details you can consult [the GNU ld manual](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ctx. I will make a try with your suggestion.